# Как задать относительный путь в проекте Qt

Tags: windows, qt, qt5

Как можно сократить строку и сделать её универсальной указав относительный путь к include'ам в .pro файле. **test_agent** - это имя/папка проекта

```
include(C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_agent\qtservice\src\qtservice.pri)
```

то есть мне необходимо заменить C:\Users\user\Desktop\ на некий аналог pwd в *unix

Comment: `$$PWD`? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#pwd

Comment: [Здесь](http://blog.mgsxx.com/?page_id=1294) есть хорошее руководство по использованию qmake.